# Issue in loading the images

Tags: android

I am using a Grid view to load images from the server and API level i am using is Level 3(1.6)
So my problem is when the images are less it upload the photo but if the number of images are more my application crashes. Can anybody tell the solution how to release the memory or force garbage collector to be call.

Comment: API Level 3 is Android 1.5 not 1.6. [See this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should scale your photos as you download them.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412168/displaying-images-and-managing-memory-in-android/5412276#5412276) for [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) usage.